# Runnig junit4 tests in junit5 environment, all test cases are failing

Tags: junit4

I am trying to use JUnit4 in JUnit5 tests environment. actuallty i have upgraded my pom to use higher version of MOckito and POwerMock.Until now, all tests were based on JUnit4. I added the platform and vintage dependencies to my pom.xml. Noow, my any test case  for JUnit4 is not  running.

Earlier pom.xml dependencies

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

    Latest pom.xml dependencies



        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.23.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>


<groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>


    i m getting below errors

     Errors: 
    [ERROR]   IntegratorAccessUpdateTest.testBeanProperties:13 » NullPointer
    [ERROR]   ActionHistoryTest.testBeanProperties » StackOverflow
    [ERROR]   ApplicationPreferenceManagerTest.testGetBoolean » NoClassDefFound org/powermoc...
    [ERROR]   ApplicationPreferenceManagerTest.testGetString » NoClassDefFound org/powermock...
    [ERROR]   CommonValidatorsDispatcherTest.setUp:25 » IllegalState Could not initialize pl...
    [ERROR]   CommonValidatorsDispatcherTest.setUp:25 » IllegalState Could not initialize pl...


  How can i remove these errors, I am not sure that changing each and every class   is feasible.is there is any compatibility issue with the versions? why is it   showing stackoverflow error?
```

Answer (score 0):

Junit provides guidance on how to upgrade from Junit4 to Junit5. 
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4

Comment: I don't want to upgrade my Junit4 tests to Junit5, but i need to run my junit4 tests in junit5 environment.